# How to show % of the total to each bar in bar graph Tableau

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api, percentage

I have an existing bar chart for a given metric that I'm trying to add a % label to each bar (customer x) to show the % of the total of another bar (All-Customers). I do not want it to replace the "Data Volume" label at the top of the each bar. I would prefer to show each customer's percentage of data volume compared to All-Customers in the Tooltip.

In my sample file, customer is simply a number (1 thru 7). Customer 99 represents All-Customers and is the sum of each customers Data Volume.  In my Tableau sheet, I made a calculated field called "Graph Labels" which takes makes my customer labels for each bar.  It adds the letter "C" to the customer #.

IF [Customer] = "99" THEN "All-customers"
ELSE "C"+STR([Customer])
END

Note: I must be able to use Graph Labels as it is in my case.  See the link for the photo of my worksheet showing the bar chart.

[Data Volume Bar Chart Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Tkg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a screenshot of what I did...

[image]

A few points:

- Instead of using "All Customers" as your last row, I filtered that one out (customer "99") and used the Row Grand Totals from the menu "Analysis > Totals > Show Row Grand Totals".
- I kept the labels as they are, but I also added the SUM(Data Volumes) in the tooltip. Only difference is that I applied a quick table calculation by right clicking on that field and selecting "Quick Table Calculation > Percent of Total".